How to fetch old data for UPS QuamtumView API using OAuth 2.0
I want to fetch old data for QuantumView API e.g for 3rd may 2024.
Whenever I am passing subscriptionfile name in the request to API.
I am getting error ‘there is no unread file for subscription’
Could you please help me in fetching the old data for any subscription name?
